# Trying to insert a ReCaptcha v2 ... but it's not displaying on the page

Tags: c#, recaptcha

To all,

I decided to add my first reCaptcha to an aspx page I created in Visual Studio.  I registered with Google to get my keys and the two lines of code I added to the page are below.

LINE OF CODE AT START OF PAGE
<%@ Register TagPrefix="recaptcha" Namespace="Recaptcha" Assembly="Recaptcha" %>

LINE OF CODE IN THE BODY OF THE PAGE

```
<recaptcha:RecaptchaControl ID="recaptcha" runat="server"
    PublicKey="6LfFWL4ZAAAAAA0ugeqZZl6vn_1cklACK-XXXXXX"
    PrivateKey="6LfFWL4ZAAAAAJMqu5H5oDvJQdkMp1ySPrXXXXXX" />
```

When the page renders, I see the code below at the site where the RecaptchaControl should be when I inspect it.  No recaptcha, though, shows up on the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var RecaptchaOptions = {
        theme : '',
        tabindex : 0
    };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LfFWL4ZAAAAAA0ugeqZZl6vn_1cklACK-1IAH4t">
</script>

You can see the page at https://johnroffers.com/Pages/ContactUs.aspx
```

Any ideas?

Greg

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any responses and saw one post that said that this two line code to use reCaptcha has been deprecated.  I found other code though a lot more lines seems to work.